# LoginViewModel. How can two constructors do it in one class [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with LoginViewModel which is as follows: In a class called "LoginViewModel" I need two constructors, one for login and one for reset. I did the constructor for login, but when I try to do the ResetPassword one as well, I get the "Method must have a return type" error which claims that I can't have two constructors with the same name.

```
namespace SchoolGrades.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Commands
        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; }
        public ICommand ResetPasswordCommand { get; }

    #endregion

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Login());
    }

    #region Private Methods

    private void Login()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

    public ResetPassword()
    {
        ResetPasswordCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Reset());
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Constructor should have name as the class name. Why can’t you initialise ResetPasswordCommand also in the same constructor?

Comment: Because I want to use different commands, each builder with his own command. Can you help me please?
The problem is that I can't have two builders with the same name

Comment: You have a good ideea!

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Why two constructors for this ? Why not lazy initializing the commands on their getter ? You don't have to initialize them in constructor. If the logic to  login and reset password is in the same class, why do you need two different instances of the class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two constructors with different names in the same class. Also, the constructor name should be the same as the class name. It should be like that below or you can create a separate view model for reset password.

```
namespace SchoolGrades.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Commands

        public ICommand LoginCommand { get; }
        public ICommand ResetPasswordCommand { get; }

        #endregion

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Login());
            ResetPasswordCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Reset());
        }

        #region Private Methods

        private void Login()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have mentioned in the comment

Comment: Yeah. I visualized it and also added another recommendation.

Comment: Thank you sirr! It's very good!